# How can I unit test Sentry's before_send callback?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, sentry

I want to write a strip_sensitive_data function and pass it into Sentry's before_send callback, as in the example from their own docs https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/filtering/?platform=python

```
import sentry_sdk

def strip_sensitive_data(event, hint):
    # modify event here
    return event

sentry_sdk.init(
    before_send=strip_sensitive_data
)
```

I'm working on a Django app and want to find a way to patch or mock this callback using Django TestCase. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, in my case I wanted to group ConnectionError and HTTPError with code 503, as there is nothing I can do about them. Here's what I came up with:

```
@pytest.fixture
def sentry_init():
    # set up sentry sdk here

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "exception, expected_fingerprint",
    [
        (ConnectionError, ["connection-error"]),
        (HTTPError("503 ..."), ["connection-error"]),
        (HTTPError("400 ..."), None), # In this case no fingerprint, I don't want any grouping
    ],
)
def test_sentry_before_send(
    monkeypatch, sentry_init, exception, expected_fingerprint  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
):
    sentry_client = sentry_sdk.Hub.current.client
    transport = MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr(sentry_client, "transport", transport)

    sentry_sdk.capture_exception(exception)

    if expected_fingerprint is not None:
        assert transport.method_calls[0].args[0]["fingerprint"] == expected_fingerprint
    else:
        assert "fingerprint" not in transport.method_calls[0].args[0].keys()
```

The transport is used to send events to sentry. So by mocking it you can test any processing you do, in `before_send` but also in `add_breadcrumbs` etc...

I had a look at the sdk tests to figure it out, in case my answer